# Uploading files to S3 using Laravel 5.1 fails

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload some files to S3 using Laravel and it's Filesystem api.

I'm getting the following error:

```
S3Exception in WrappedHttpHandler.php line 159:
Error executing "PutObject" on "https://s3..amazonaws.com/example-bucket/433922_1448096894943.png"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: s3.global.amazonaws.com (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

here are my settings in the /config/filesystems.php file

```
    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key'    => 'apiKey',
        'secret' => 'secretApiKey',
        'region' => 'global',
        'bucket' => 'example-bucket',
    ],
```

as noted in the error, the filesystem api can't resolve the following domain name

```
s3.global.amazonaws.com
```

the "global" part in here stands for the region but as far I understand S3 no longer requires a region.

while I think that the actual domain name should like this

```
example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/
```

here is the code I am using to invoke the filesystem api

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put('new-name.png', file_get_contents( 'path/to/file'))
```

Comment: `s3.global.amazonaws.com` does exist and resolves to an IP. There's a chance that there're no DNS servers listed on your server to resolve domain names

Comment: I just tried resolving s3.global.amazonaws.com on both my personal laptop and my server and it didn't resolve : (. I've also tried s3.us-east.amazonaws.com, which I think is a valid region, but that didn't work either

Comment: Just tried s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com and that did resolve : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to set up the correct S3 region, which in my case was: eu-west-1, and it all started working.